# static_assert failed "Types with user specified constructors (non-aggregate initializable types) are not supported

Tags: smart-contract, compilation

I am writing a smart contract for use with the EOSIO system contract, and am receiving this error message multiple times when I try to compile the code.

I have checked my constructors and they are all correct - is there something obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem - the problem was caused by the fact I was not setting default constructors for each class that produced this error message.

```
class x
{
// Private variables

public:
  x(){/* Default constructor here */}
};
```

This solved the problem. It seems that all classes that are to be used as multi_index arrays need a default constructor, even if the default constructor is blank.